# I'm trying to add code onto this which allows me to check and give a response if i enter a negative in the active shell

Tags: python, python-3.10

```py
print('How many cats do you have?')
numCats = input()
try:
    if int(numCats) >= 4:
        print('That is a lot of cats.')
    else:
        print('That is not that many cats.')
    except ValueError:
    print('You did not enter a number.')
def check_negative(s):
    try:
        if int(numCats) <=0
            print('You cant have negative cats.')
        else:
            print('That is not that many cats.')
```

I get invalid syntax and im unsure what im doing wrong. Im pretty new to this sort of stuff so nay help is appreciated.

Comment: please don't paste your code as plain text. you can use the markdown syntax to highlight your code. The SO website has good tutorial on how to use markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few syntax error in your code, and also you can just add negative check in the try-catch along with `>= 4` check.

```py
print('How many cats do you have?')
numCats = input()
try:
    if int(numCats) <0:
        print('You cant have negative cats.')
    elif int(numCats) >= 4:
        print('That is a lot of cats.')
    else:
        print('That is not that many cats.')
except ValueError:
    print('You did not enter a number.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_negatives():
    if numCats < 0:
        print("You cannot have negative cats")


numCats = int(input("How many cats do you have?\n- "))

if numCats >= 4:
    print("That is a lot of cats")
elif 4 > numCats > 0:
    print("That is not many cats")
else:
     check_negatives()
```

The numCats takes an integer input and the \n adds a new line. It then checks if numCats is greater than or equal to 4, if so, then it prints "That is a lot of cats". If numCats if below 4, BUT also above 0 (so not negative) it prints "That is not many cats". Finally you don't need the check_negatives function since being negative is the only other possibility, but I included it.

You can just leave it at

```
else:
     print("You cannot have negative cats")
```